# Android JetPack Navigation : How to open a fragment from an activity not associated with it?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

scenario :

**`MainActivity.kt`** : `activity_main.xml` contains `my_nav_host_fragment`

in `mobile_navigation.xml` *first_frag_dest* is the startDestination and there is *second_frag_dest* also, with respective classes `FirstFragment.kt` and `SecondFragment.kt`.

I have setup bottom navigation for switch between two fragments using the Android Jetpack Navigation components.

When the Second Fragment is opened for the first time if FirbaseUser is null,  A Welcome Activity is launched which is configured for GoogleSignInusing Firebase.

In `WelcomeActivity.java` I have a function `updateUI(user: FirebaseUser)` to update the UI.

Now, what code should I write in updateUI function such that I am redirected back to the Second Fragment.

Please tell how to do it using JetPack Navigation components.

*Note: Principles of navigation say that only one activity must exist but here I am compelled to use an Activity for GoogleSignIn due to Firebase restrictions.*

Comment: So your first activity is already on `SecondFragment` and launches your `WelcomeActivity`. And you just want to return to `SecondFragment`?

Comment: @ianhanniballake yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to close your `WelcomeActivity` and return to the activity below it, have your `updateUI` method call [`finish()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()):

> Call this when your activity is done and should be closed

Comment: Is there some way to do it using jetpack Navigation?

Comment: No, Navigation focuses on a [Single Activity model](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2k8x8V77CrU) and has no concept of finishing an activity.

Comment: But in my case I needed to have another activity, so in that case what should I do.

Comment: Call `finish()`.

Comment: @ianhanniballake wouldn't `ActivityCompat.finishAfterTransition(..)` be more appropriate?