# android architecture components : What is the alternative to fragment container in android architecture navigation?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I want to achieve the same result as this code, As I am using android navigation components what should I out in place of the fragment container as there is only NavHostFragment.

```
val newFragment = ExampleFragment()
val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment)
transaction.addToBackStack(null)
transaction.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a destination in your navigation graph that looks like:

```
<fragment
  android:id="@+id/example"
  android:name=".ExampleFragment"/>
```

You'd simply call `navController.navigate(R.id.example)`, getting a reference to your `NavController` via one of the methods described in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-implementing#Tie-ui).

Comment: This method is not working in my case, I have explained my full situation in another question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53854226/android-jetpack-navigation-how-to-open-a-fragment-from-an-activity-not-associa)